# Power just went off and my html code turned into binary (sublime text)

Tags: html, debugging, binary

As I mentioned in the title, the power went of for 2 minutes, and my PC turned off while I was writing some HTML. After I turned it back on my code turned into binary and I don't know how to recover it. I use Sublime Text 3. I've also tried opening it in Notepad++, but it looks the same.
[Sublime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Ql0.png)

[Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0QIq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](https://v2.cryptii.com/binary/text) something that can help you?

I don't know if the binaries are the compiled HTML code or just plain text symbols calculated into binaries.

If the second one is the case then you might be able to recover it with something like the link above. Of course if sublime encodes with 16 or 32 bits "per sign" then you will have to use some other algorithm. This should not be too difficult to implement though (in Java for example).

If the text looks like
0101010001101000011001010010000001110001
then every sign is encoded with exacly the same number of bits so you can just try to split it every 8th bit (or 16th, or 32nd) and use the above or equal algorithm to decode that.

If your binaries is a compiled code then I am not aware of any way to decompile binaries into HTML although such algorithm should exist somewhere.

EDIT: Be aware that, since your editor broke unexpectedly, the file might be corrupt and the code will be slightly different or destroyed completely. In this case there is nothing you can do, unless the corruption can be undone.

Comment: Thank you. The tool that you posted in the first link helped me. I managed to get the code fixed .